# present perfect or past simple

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

Is it possible to write

> I have woken up very early today because I don't want to miss my favourite Tv show

or

> I woke up  very early today because I don't want to miss my favourite tv show

In both cases I mean that the tv show is in the future, it has not happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. Their usage( present perfect/past tense) depends on the time you are talking  For example  if it it still morning , when you are saying it, then, the present perfect tense is correct.  to miss my favourite tv show.**I have woken up very early today because I don't want to miss my favourite tv show.****. (The use of the present  perfect tense here, tells us it's still morning,a , ), and it implies that the TV show will be shown  at some time in the morning. (Why else, would you wake up early?). or I **woke up very early today because I don't want to miss my favourite tv show.** ( The past tense here shows us that it isn't morning any longer; it might be noon, afternoon,etc). Although the second sentence seems correct, waking up very early to watch a TV show at noon, in the afternoon ,etc, doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: ahh, @Vic's re the second sentence. I recall mixing tense in a sentence is wrong (woke and do), but writers do it often. The logic is also a bit whacky. I could have woken up early because I'm stressed out about missing the show taking place 10 hours later, but then it should read: I woke up early .. because I *didn't* want to miss my show. Right? The first sentence seems clunky. (I'm American; I'll bet you speak the Queen's English, right? And, yes, I think you all have a better grasp of usage than we do :-0 )

Comment: I agree with you, and as a matter of fact, I was brought up in New Jersey. The second sentence can be used  when implying that I was so excited that I woke up 10 hours earlier to not miss my favourite show.  The first one just makes more sense.

Comment: @HowardPautz I don't believe there are any rules in English against mixing tenses in a sentence unless the actions described should be in the same tense anyway, regardless of whether they are in the same sentence. There might be style rules recommending against it, but not grammatical rules.

Answer (score 0):

If the TV show is a future event:

Your first sentence can work, if by the time you say it the show has not been seen yet.

The past tense suggests an event happened in the past, so it would not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "I woke up early in the morning".  Your waking up is situated in the past and has no relation to the moment when you say or write this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You should use present perfect in a case if now is still a morning and you are just explaining to someone (e.g. your friend) why you have woken up so early today. So, the occasion you are talking about influences the situation you're in right now.